# Bind checkbox values to parent-child model

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, bind

I am developing application to bind the checkbox for role based menu. In that, I have parent-child check box and I want to bind the checkbox checked value from the input **1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3**.

I have googled many things and implemented few too but there is no idea for parent child checked values selection.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="1">Upload
    <ul>
      <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="1">Large </li>
      <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="2">Small </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="2">Move</li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="3">Producs</li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="5">User</li>
</ul>
```

**Binding Input**

> 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3

**Expected Selection**

[image]

Comment: Do you have to mark the checkbox based on the binding input or?

Comment: Do you want the change the value itself or just want the get the result as mentioned?

Comment: So if that's not what you want, what ***do*** you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to set the checkbox to checked based on the input, if so then you can try this:

```
var bindingInput = "1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3".split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < bindingInput.length; i++) {
  var inputvalue = bindingInput[i].trim();
  if (inputvalue.indexOf('.') > 0) {
    var child = inputvalue.split('.');
    var ele = $('.check_container > li > .check_box[value=' + child[0] + ']');
    for (var t = 1; t < child.length; t++){
      ele = ele.next("ul").find(' > li > .check_box[value=' + child[t] + ']');
    }
    ele.prop("checked", true)
  } else {
    $('.check_container > li > .check_box[value=' + inputvalue + ']').prop("checked", true)
  }
}
```

Please note I did add the class `check_container` to the first `ul`

**Demo**

```js
var bindingInput = "1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3, 1.1.1".split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < bindingInput.length; i++) {
  var inputvalue = bindingInput[i].trim();
  if (inputvalue.indexOf('.') > 0) {
    var child = inputvalue.split('.');
    var ele = $('.check_container > li > .check_box[value=' + child[0] + ']');
    for (var t = 1; t < child.length; t++) {
      ele = ele.next("ul").find(' > li > .check_box[value=' + child[t] + ']');
    }
    ele.prop("checked", true)
  } else {
    $('.check_container > li > .check_box[value=' + inputvalue + ']').prop("checked", true)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="check_container">
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="1">Upload
    <ul>
      <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="1">Large
        <ul>
          <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="1">Large2 </li>
          <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="2">Large2 </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="2">Small </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="2">Move</li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="3">Producs</li>
  <li><input class="check_box" type="checkbox" value="5">User</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much.. Will this work if i have input as *1.1.1*, Means <li> under two parents of <ul>.

Comment: @VigneshKumarA I've added a little update to the code `ele = ele.next("ul").find(' > li > .check_box[value=' + child[t] + ']');`